# How to use intel opencl sdk in Clion in windows 10?

Tags: c++, opencl, intel, clion

I have installed Intel opencl sdk for windows and opencl variable are added to the environment variables. I want to use this sdk with my Clion ide which I am unable to include it in my current project since it was CL/cl.hpp not found. How can add it to my project in Clion?

Cl/cl.hpp is located at`C:\Program Files(x86)\IntelSWTools\OpenCL\sdk\include\CL`

following is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
project(tpch_framework)

# enable c++11
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")

find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)

if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif() 

# Configure required Boost libraries
set(BOOST_ROOT "" CACHE PATH "Boost build root (useful on Windows)")
option(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS
       "Search for static boost libs" OFF)
option(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED
       "Search for multithreaded boost libs" ON)
option(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME
       "Search for boost libs linked against static C++ runtime" OFF)
find_package(Boost 1.47.0 REQUIRED filesystem system)

# ensure that dependant libraries not explicitly specified here
# are found by the linker:
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

#Bring the headers into the project
include_directories(include)

FILE(GLOB_RECURSE INC_ALL "include/*.hpp")

#However, the file(GLOB...) allows for wildcard additions:
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")

add_library(tpch_framework ${SOURCES})
add_executable(framework main.cpp ${INC_ALL})
target_link_libraries(framework tpch_framework)
#target_link_libraries(framework stdc++fs)
target_link_libraries(framework ${LIBS})
```

Comment: I guess, that you've got CMake project in CLion. Did you add `find_package( OpenCL REQUIRED )` to your `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Comment: Yes I have added it there but still its the same error

Comment: Can you update your question with `CMakeLists.txt` file content? It'll be easier to determine what is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide information about include directory for `OpenCL` headers like you provided for `Boost` headers. Also, you need to link `OpenCL` libraries with your target.

In your CMakeLists...

For include and link directories:

```
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${OpenCL_LIBRARY})
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

For linking libraries:

```
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCL_LIBRARY})
```